# Gatling: java equivalent of wsAwait from scala

Tags: gatling

Is there some java equivalent to the following code in Gatling scala? esp the wsAwait class:

```
wsAwait.within(10).until(1).regex("")
```

This is from a sample scala project using dependency gatling-http-2.3.1.jar and I saw in package io.gatling.http.check.async the `trait AsyncCheckSupport extends AsyncCheckDSL`. But this is not included in the gatling-http-3.7.3.jar used in my java test project.

Is there a new way to do this in the latest version? Their documentation does not have any example using this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using Gatling 2, that has been dead for year and whose last release was in March 2018.
The WebSocket support was completely redesigned in Gatling 3, which was released 3 years ago. Please check the [migration guides](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/upgrading/) for the new WebSocket API.